# 2-D FFT using MPI_Alltoall in MPI

Tags: mpi, fft

I have a **4X6** matrix split as *two* **2X6** matrices on **2** processors. Since the rows have been split in a contiguous way (*C Language*) on the processors, we can carry out a **1-D FFT** on the rows. The problem is we need an `MPI_Alltoall()` to collect contiguous columns on a particular processor for **1-D column FFT** i.e. Processor 0 has:

```
A B C D E F
G H I J K L
```

Processor 1 has:

```
M N O P Q R
S T U V W X
```

The `MPI_Alltoall()` needs to convert this to the following on Processor 0:

```
A G M S
B H N T
C I O U
```

And the following on Processor 2:

```
D J P V
E K Q W
F L R X
```

I tried to define a *vector* having *count=2, blocklength=1, stride=6* as the sending type vector, set its *extent* to `MPI_INT`, *displacement* to 0 and sent 3 instances of this vector using `MPI_Alltoall()`. This according to me should send `A G, B H,` and `C I` to processor 0 and `D J, E K,` and `F L` to processor 1. Similarly `M S, N T,` and `O U` to processor 0 and `P V, Q W,` and `R X` to processor 1. 
Is my interpretation correct ? If yes, then how do I receive these 3 instances of vectors on the receiving side ( What/How do I define the datatype?).